# Lenet convolution neural network implementation in python using theano giving same error value in simultaneous training

Tags: python, theano, convolution

I am a newbie to convolution neural network and theano. So I tried to run the code from the tutorial http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html . The code was working good but the output seems to be wrong. For the initialization of weights, we are using the "numpy.random.RandomState(23455)" values. I ran two instances of the code and in each instance, the error value was "cost_ij=2.302585". How is that possible ?? We are using different random numbers on both neural networks, So how could the output be the same??  for getting fast result, I changed the number of epochs as 1, patience=10 and patience increase as 2.

I am getting a warning:: "/convolutional_mlp.py:97: UserWarning: The `image_shape` keyword argument to `tensor.nnet.conv2d` is deprecated, it has been renamed to `input_shape`." Is this the reason for the network to behave like the same???

If we are using different weights, don't we need to get different outputs ??

```
output1::

training @ iter =  0
cost = 2.302585
cost = 2.284162

output 2::


training @ iter =  0
cost = 2.302585
cost = 2.284162
```

Thanks in advance for the answers...

Comment: the error was due to 2 reasons: one was due to the case that , the last layer's weight was initialized by zero and the learning rate was high(.1 in this case). Now the program is running fine after the reduction of learning parameter.